# Can't load template from an Angular route in a Django project

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

In my **urls.py**, I have the following patterns:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^setup/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Both the patterns ultimately resolve to the same view, as the logic is handled in the Controllers. The view kinda looks like something like this:

```
def index(request):
    return request(request, 'index.html', {})
```

In my **index.html** file, I load in Angular, my Angular App, the routes, and everything else.

My angular routes look something like this:

```
.when('/', {
    controller : 'BaseController',
    templateUrl : 'static/app_partials/base.html',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
.when('/products/', {
    controller : 'ProductsController',
    templateUrl : 'static/app_partials/products.html',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

Now, when I go to the first URL in my pattern, everything works nicely, and the route is able to load the template perfectly, as the url is `http://example.com/static/app_partials/base.html`, which is exactly where the file is.

However, the second URL does not work, as the template being called now is `http://example.com/setup/static/app_partials/base.html`, which does not exist.

How can I fix this issue? I have tried to put the whole URL in my routes, with the domain and stuff, but then I get a insecure URL error. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use absolute URLs, e.g. `/static/app_partials/base.html` instead of relative urls like `static/app_partials/base.html`.

Comment: @Alasdair - That fixed the issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute URLs (with a leading slash) instead of relative URLs.

For example use `/static/app_partials/base.html` instead of `static/app_partials/base.html`